# How to specify a different column for a @Inheritance JPA annotation

Tags: java, jpa

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Foo   

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class BarFoo extends Foo

mysql> desc foo;
+---------------+-------------+
| Field         | Type        |
+---------------+-------------+
| id            | int         |
+---------------+-------------+

mysql> desc barfoo;
+---------------+-------------+
| Field         | Type        |
+---------------+-------------+
| id            | int         |
| foo_id        | int         |
| bar_id        | int         |
+---------------+-------------+

mysql> desc bar;
+---------------+-------------+
| Field         | Type        |
+---------------+-------------+
| id            | int         |
+---------------+-------------+
```

Is it possible to specify column barfo.foo_id as the joined column?

Are you allowed to specify barfoo.id as BarFoo's @Id since you are overriding the getter/seeter of class Foo?

I understand the schematics behind this relationship (or at least I think I do) and I'm ok with them.

The reason I want an explicit id field for BarFoo is exactly because I want to avoid using a joined key (foo _id, bar _id) when querying for BarFoo(s) or when used in a "stronger" constraint. (as Ruben put it)

Comment: Querying for BarFoo and Foo can be done separately, and constraints on the Id can be stronger for BarFoo than for Foo, while still having the same key.

I do not directly see the use of choosing a joined inheritance strategy and having different Id's for superclass and subclass.

Comment: Since barfoo.id won't be unique, how can you either query for an explicit BarFoo or use it as a fk constraint to another table?

Comment: Since barfoo.id won't be unique, how can you either query for an explicit BarFoo: When querying with HQL you can simply query for BarFoo instead of Foo. When querying from SQL you can use a join between the the BarFoo and Foo tables.

Comment: Since barfoo.id won't be unique, how can you use it as a fk constraint to another table : create a JPA association between the BarFoo class and class X using JPA. Foo does not need to be involved in this.

Comment: All the above are valid. But they don't actually answer my question.
Since the relationship is ManyToMany between Foo and Bar that means that BarFoo will have a ManyToOne with Foo. Hence you need the id column to explicitly refer to a specific BarFoo. 
Maybe that means though that you can't actually implement a OneToMany relationship as Inheritance therefore my whole question isn't relevant to begin with.

Comment: BarFoo can have a many-to-many relationship with Foo's while it is a subclass of Foo. But you can not model the many-to-many relationship as inheritance.

You need to use the @ManyToMany association. The Java Persistence with Hibernate book by Christian Bauer and Gavin King is one of the better books on using JPA and Hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When InheritanceType.JOINED is defined the @Id column will automatically be used for joining. There is only one id value for a Barfoo instance, and this is persisted in the id column of both the foo and the barfoo table.

There is no need to have separate id and foo_id columns in the barfoo table. Nor is it necessary by default to overwrite the id getter and setter in barfoo. You would only overwrite the id setter and getter if the id of a Barfoo instance has stronger constraints than the id of a Foo instance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CHILD_PK1", 
        referencedColumnName="PARENT_PK1"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CHILD_PK2",
        referencedColumnName="PARENT_PK2")
})
public class Child extends Parent {
    ...
}
```